# Firefox/Opera show HTML page Source instead Content?

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, safari, opera

I created a simple HTML Server with LUA (corona environment)

Anyhow while connecting from Safari/Chrome the Page is displayed fine,
but with Opera/Firefox, I get instead the Source Code shown instead??

Do i have to send kind a PreHeader or what can be the reason.

For example

```
<html>
  <body>
     hello <strong>test</strong> how are you
  </body>
</html>
```

Safari/Chrome does show as expected just:   "     hello **test** how are you   "

But Opera/Firefox does show the source itself as example above!!?

Any Ideas

Update:
Now I implemented a meta tag Content Header.... still the same !!
Firefox/opera do show the source instead the content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
   testa asdfa asf asdf asdf asdf
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Did you set the Content-Type header to text/html ?

Comment: What are the exact headers your server sends?  Use `wget -S` or equivalent to get those.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTTP response (from the server), you need to send the Content-Type header, i.e.

```
Content-Type:   text/html
```

Answer (score 1):

ok.. solved it...
had to send

```
    client:send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
```

before anything else

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost certainly because you have not sent the `Content-type` header. You'll want to try to send it somehow. Set it to `text/html`.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't set content-type via meta headers. It has to be sent on the server side in the HTTP response header. Think for a moment: if it's reading it as plaintext, it will never even so much as parse the meta tag! The reason some browsers are displaying it properly is because they are trying to work around the fact that your server is not providing the necessary header.